# which datastructure should i use based on my needs?

Tags: java, data-structures, architecture

**Needs:**

- Storing objects of a class which overrides equals and hash code
- Will be looping and shoving objects into the datastructure
- Need to be able to call `contains` to check whether a certain object is stored in the structure
- If `contains` returns true then fetch that specific object from the structure and call a certain `getter` on that object

**Options I've considered:**

- Map - this works for all the needs but I don't really have a map (key and a value). all I have is bunch of objects. Would it be a good practice to forcefully use a map by storing objects as key and integer or something in the value?
- Set would work, however, it doesn't have a fetch method like get.
- List would also work, but it doesn't have a method to fetch that is non index based. Meaning, once `contains` returns true I'll have to loop through the list to find the index of my particular object and then fetch it.

I'm open to using different libraries like apache commons or guava for example.

Comment: Funny, you don't want a map, but you need a fetch method :-) And what do you want to fetch? The objects I suppose. And based on what criteria? And no, it is not such a good idea to store objects as key (set?) and integer as a value. That's wasting memory and introducing another vector of debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> List would also work, but it doesn't have a method to fetch that is non index based.

`List` has an [`indexOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method which will do exactly what you want.

Comment: He doesn't need the `indexOf` method, because his objects are not to be retrieved by an index, which is a specialization of a key. This is also mentioned somewhat by the last paragraph in OPs question.

Comment: Did you read the last point of the OP? He says that a `List` is not appropriate, since he cannot get the index of the object he uses for `contains()`. This is where `indexOf()` helps.

Comment: No, what he said was "List would also work, but it doesn't have a method to fetch that is non index based". He wants a method that is **not** index based. That's because he doesn't know indexes. What he will do is create an object, and since the class implements `equals`, he will simply call `contains`. Of course, it all depends on the `equals` implementation.

Comment: @amn I think you misunderstood the OP. The index based method is `get(index)`. Ask OP for clarification before downvoting!

Comment: @amn.. He didn't knew that he has a method called :- `indexOf` that can fetch him an `index`. He don't want to `Loop`, which he will have to do in case of a `Set`, which you have suggested.

Comment: He doesn't need to loop over anything, that's what a set implementation does for him, and **that is why** he needs it. Look at my code please, to see what I am getting at. The `equals` method is what makes it all work.

Comment: @amn. Common man. Can't you re-read the OP rather than arguing?? Why do you think he doesn't need to iterate?? How would you fetch data from a `Set` without looping??

Comment: @amn. To use `equals` method, you need to have an object to compare, where will you get it from?

Comment: @amn.. Till now I haven't down-voted you. Because I'm not a down-voter. But you need to improve your post, and remove your down-vote. Else I have no other options

Answer (score 2):

Although the `best thing` to use in this `scenario` would be a **`Map`**, because it offers fast retrieval based on `Key-Value` pair.

But `List` also allows to fetch data based on index.

So, you can use either a `List` or a `Map`. But to make your task easier, I would prefer a `Map`. Because i case of `Map` you won't have to search for an `index` of an Object, then get the `Object` at that index. Fetching is just a `one-line` operation.

```
// When using a List.
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
if (myList.contains("rohit")) {
    myList.get(myList.indexOf("rohit"));
}

// When using Map.
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
// You can directly fetch your object, based on some Key if you have one..
myMap.get("key");
```

Comment: Why a downvote? It would be more productive to leave a comment after you downvote. So that the post can be improvised.

Comment: Certainly @Rohit. Based on OPs criteria, your answer is simply not a good one. I am sorry to come across like this. Please check his explicit requirements - what he needs is a set. You simply emulate a set with your list, why? A set is made to provide a `contains` method, to make use of `equals` and `hashCode`, for "looping and shoving" objects into it, and if you want to check if it contains an object then you (again) call the `contains(object)`.

Comment: @amn.. And you must also notice that he don't want to **iterate** to fetch the data. Set does not have a method to fetch on index. So, even if he knows that Set contains the object, he would have to iterate.. Thats why I posted two options.

Comment: Really? And how will he know what object to fetch from your list?

Comment: @amn.. You didn't see my example?? using `indexOf()` method. I have posted the code

Comment: let's see what OP chooses and whether he can make a set work for him. I will then of couse remove the downvote!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17926/discussion-between-amn-and-rohit-jain)

Answer (score -2):

You need a set. You don't need a fetch method (you think you do), because like you said you only have a bunch of objects. And since these use `equals` and `hashCode`, a set is exactly what you need.

Of course a map could do as well, because its keys is a set as well, but in the end you need to  better specify your requirements, as it appears you are a bit confused as to the purpose of your data structure. From what I understand, you do not need a map indeed.

A hash set implementation will do. Here is what you can do with it all:

```
class Foo
{
    final String name;

    Foo(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return (obj instanceof Foo) && ((Foo)obj).name.equals(name);
    }
}

Set<Foo> fooSet = new HashSet<Foo>();

fooSet.add(new Foo("someFoo"));

assert fooSet.contains(new Foo("someFoo"));
```

Comment: @amn.. Ok, now you know that your Set contains your object.. Now how would you fetch it? Using `loop` ofcourse. That is what OP don't want. Please re-read the OP

Comment: No, you do not understand well what `equals` does - if objects are equal, you do not need the "original" object. The encapsulation of data within the object makes sure that you can use whatever new object you have created that equals the object in the set. **Unless* of course, he **does need an index or a key**, which makes my answer invalid. But that depends on the nature of his objects. I am merely replying to his requirements.

Comment: @amn `contains()` will only tell him that it is contained, but there is no other way than looping to get it. A `list` also has `contains()` but in addition there is `indexOf()`. If you argue that he does not have to get the object back from the `Collection` then it does not make any difference if you use `List` or `Set`. There is no reason to downvote if I suggest a `List`.

Comment: @amn.. Ok, here I'll try to clarify. Suppost OP wants to check whether the List contains an `Object` or not. Now, you're right that he can check it with `contains` method and use the `object` which he is comparing with. But what if he wants to modify the `Object` inside the Set?? how you approach this case? huh?

Comment: @Baz, you *do not need* to get anything - the `equals` means objects are equal, and either one will do. Two string objects are considered equal if both have say "apple" as value, even if they are actually two distinct objects occupying different locations in memory. Your lists and/or maps retrieve the original object for him, which defeats the point of `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: @amn Not if you just use `contains()`. Which you can with a `List`.

Comment: Correct @Rohit, if he wants to modify the original object, he will  have to use some sort of map. But he did not specify that, while he did specify he will use `equals` which already implies a lot. I merely fulfill his requirements.

Comment: @amn Of course he specified that: "_If contains returns true then fetch that specific object from the structure and call a certain getter on that object_". You should read more carefully.

Comment: @amn. But you didn't yet justified your down-vote? I'm not saying you are wrong anywhere. But neither of the posts that you down-voted, conveys any wrong method. In fact they are more confortable to work with..

Comment: @Baz indeed, but then he does not need `equals` or his `equals` (and `hashCode`) will **always** return `false` for two different objects, even if these can be said to contain same state.

Comment: @amn.. `If contains returns true then fetch that specific object from the structure and call a certain getter on that object`. I think you forgot to read that last line in hurry to answer..

Comment: @amn Since OP accepted my answer I will assume that I got his question right... Now please remove that downvote.

Comment: @amn the two objects compared using `contains` are equal based on a certain criteria in my equals method. However, I still need to change the object by calling more setters on it.

Comment: Then you *may* have to debug your application later where two "equal" objects have different state, because you modified the one but not the other. But you are right, and I understand now that you wanted something else than a set.